# Perl script to parse output of cvs log command

Tags: perl, cvs

Does anyone have a perl script or package that parses the output of a cvs log command and turns it into perl structures for further processing?

Answer (score 2):

I have used this script to convert "cvs log" output into XML. You might find it useful:

http://www.red-bean.com/cvs2cl/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/bonsai/